# Tooltip testing in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Is there a way in cypress to test the tooltip info when hover over in different places?

Ex: I hover over a graph, which shows different values when hover over different places

hovering over 0,0 displays (x=0,y=0) in tooltip and so on.. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this: `cy.trigger('mousedown', x, y)`. Then you can do `cy.get('.tooltip-selector').should('contains', 'value')`

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me

Comment: @KevinOswaldo glad to read that. Can you approve my answer to make it more visible for others?

Comment: Hello I'm not the author of the question, can I do that?

Comment: You're right, my bad :)

Comment: What if the tooltip's component cannot be captured or it cannot be located?

Comment: @PraveenPandey- Use Cypress Test Runner's Selector Playground as it freezes AUT. Refer- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/cypress-app#Selector-Playground